# Powershell quser & logoff

Tags: powershell, puppet

Trying to create a script to log off users that have been idle for more than 10 minutes. **My idle time -gt does not work.**

```
foreach ($user in quser | select ID, username, 'idle time' )   {

if($user.'IDLE TIME' -gt 10) {

    logoff /server:localhost  $user.ID
    $Output = "Logging off $user.username"}
}  

else {$Output = "No users to log off" }

}
```

thank you for any help

This worked in the end, but I have configured script as following, but did not use idletime, just listed the usernames to be logged off from the server. The below is running via puppet so it only performs the action between 2 - 5 in the morning.

```
$localServerName = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Name
$servername = $localServerName.Name
$Jallie =@()
foreach($users in Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName $localServerName.Name | where {$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'} )
{
     $temp = " " | select Processname,Username,SessionId
     $temp.Processname = $users.ProcessName
     $temp.Username = $users.GetOwner().user
     $temp.Sessionid = $users.SessionId
     $Jallie += $temp
}
$servername = $localServerName.Name
foreach($element in $Jallie)
{
      if($element.username -eq 'user1')
      {
            logoff $element.Sessionid /SERVER:$servername
            'Logging off ' + $element.username
      }
      elseif($element.username -eq 'user2')
      {
            logoff $element.Sessionid /SERVER:$servername
            'Logging off ' + $element.username
      }

}
```

Comment: hello see [idlquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845508/get-idle-time-of-machine)

Comment: `quser` doesn't return a powershell object, so you can't select the columns in the way you're trying and thus can't compare any values

Comment: To continue from arco `idle time` might be be in the format you would expect. Mine is "2+19:53" for example so using `-gt 10` might lead to odd results.

Comment: thanks, ill try and find another command

Comment: Not quite the same, but this at least gives you a list of current users.

Comment: Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'} | select name, __SERVER,@{n="owner";e={$_.getowner().user}}

Comment: See: [Easier way to parse 'query user' in PowerShell (or quser)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39212183/1701026)