# POWERSHELL - How to convert the command qwinsta into a table object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a table object with the result of the qwinsta command but I cannot do it.
could you help me ?

So I have declare my table like this :

```
$UserSession = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "SessionName" = "" ;
            "Username" = " " ;
            "ID" = " " ;
            "State" = " " ;
            "Type" = "" ;
            "Device" = " " ;
         }
```

but now how I can populate this table with the result of the command qwinsta?

Comment: Did you try to search for it before you came here to ask for?  ;-)  [https://theposhwolf.com/howtos/A-better-way-to-find-logged-on-users-remotely-using-PowerShell/](https://theposhwolf.com/howtos/A-better-way-to-find-logged-on-users-remotely-using-PowerShell/)

Comment: thank you for your return, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: My answer to a similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62491383/6654942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to have a script that does this very thing, so I'll give the below example:

```
qwinsta /server:$computer |
ForEach{

       If($_ -notmatch "SESSIONNAME")
        {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property `
        @{
         "ID"           = [Int]$_.SubString(41,05).Trim()
         "ComputerName" = $Computer
         "User"         = $_.SubString(19,22).Trim()
         "State"        = $_.SubString(47,08).Trim()
         }
        }
```

Obviously in my case there's an outer look of computers as well, but this should demonstrate the point.  You need to identify the positions of the fields you're interested in and string parse them out then assign them as properties to your object.