# Powershell User State - QUser

Tags: powershell

I am using the below powershell script (Currently works) to pull the quser.exe data. I am trying to use this data to pull the state of each logged in user, as quser does. I need to use the Disc state in an if statement, but I am unable to pull JUST the Disc or Active state using the results of this script. Any advice?

```
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
       [String[]]$ComputerNames = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
 
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerNames) {
       $stringOutput = quser /server:$Computer 2>$null
       If (!$stringOutput) {Write-Warning "Unable to retrieve quser info for `"$Computer`""}
       ForEach ($line in $stringOutput) {
          If ($line -match "logon time") {Continue}
 
          $idleStringValue = $line.SubString(54, 9).Trim().Replace('+', '.')
          If ($idleStringValue -eq "none") {$idle = $null}
          Else {$idle = [timespan]$idleStringValue}
 
          [PSCustomObject]@{Username = $line.SubString(1, 20).Trim()
                             SessionName = $line.SubString(23, 17).Trim()
                             ID = $line.SubString(42, 2).Trim()
                             State = $line.SubString(46, 6).Trim()
                             IdleTime = $idle
                             LogonTime = [datetime]$line.SubString(65)
                          }
       } 
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean the user state? You can just erase the properties in your `PSCustomObject` that you don't need, or pipe to `Select-Object`, `Foreach-Object`, or using the grouping operator `(scriptcall).State`.

Comment: There's an extra bracket at the end.  You mean like `.\script localhost | select state`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala
I removed the suggested properties and it does indeed now only show "Disc", though it does show it twice. But that's fine, I can work with that. I am currently using the below after the quser script, to force reboot the device if there is a Disc state user. Now my only question left, is will an Active user, that is logged in, become a Disc user if the screen locks or the system goes idle? I can't seem to find that answer anywhere.

`$StateTest=Get-Quser
If 
("$StateTest" -like "*Disc*")
{Restart-Computer -Force}`

Comment: Now, if I could somehow TARGET the specific user that is in a Disc state and force log them off instead, that would be the way I'd prefer to go. But I am not having any luck with that.

Comment: Does this script work for you https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/5014-get-quser? It's a function so it needs to be loaded first, and as for your comment, you can use `Where-Object` to filter for that user.

Comment: See: [Easier way to parse 'query user' in PowerShell (or quser)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39212183/1701026)