# PowerShell - Enumerate results from a query

Tags: windows, powershell

I am building out a PowerShell script to return the number of disconnected sessions on a Windows server. I'm running into an issue where I can query the sessions on a server but can't enumerate them into a counter.

For starters I query the active sessions:

```
query user /server:$SERVER
```

Which returns...

```
 USERNAME       SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 user1                              5  Disc     10+14:30  8/3/2023 12:23 PM
 user2                              6  Disc     10+13:38  8/3/2023 6:15 PM
 user3                             10  Disc      5+01:03  8/9/2023 8:27 AM
>iamtheadmin    rdp-tcp#3          14  Active          .  8/14/2023 9:47 AM
```

Great! Next I try to take the results and convert them into an integer that I can use to do other things (shutdown, reboot, send a notification, etc).

```
# Initialize a counter for disconnected sessions
$disconnectedSessionCount = 0

# Iterate through each line of the session information
foreach ($line in $sessionInfo) {
    # Split the line into words
    $words = $line -split '\s+'
    
    # Check if the session state is "Disc" (disconnected)
    if ($words[2] -eq "Disc") {
        # Increment the disconnected session counter
        $disconnectedSessionCount++
    }
}

# Output the number of disconnected sessions
Write-Host "Number of Disconnected Sessions: $disconnectedSessionCount"
```

No matter what I do the number of sessions that get written out is zero...always zero. I can't figure out where I went wrong in my logic so any help would be appreciated.

Attempted to write script that enumerates the number of disconnected sessions on a Windows server. Unfortunately I always get the same result.

Comment: Did you assign `query user /server:$SERVER` to `$sessionInfo` somewhere? I don't see it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In comparison to the output of a PowerShell [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)s as e.g. `Get-Content`, the external command `Query User` (`$sessionInfo`) apparently doesn't result in a collection of lines but a single [here string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/): a string containing multiple lines which you have to split into lines first, something like: `-Split '[\r?\n]'` .

Anyways, consider (re)using this general [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet or any of the suggestions here: [Easier way to parse 'query user' in PowerShell (or quser)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39212183/1701026):

```
$sessionInfo = @'
 USERNAME       SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 user1                              5  Disc     10+14:30  8/3/2023 12:23 PM
 user2                              6  Disc     10+13:38  8/3/2023 6:15 PM
 user3                             10  Disc      5+01:03  8/9/2023 8:27 AM
>iamtheadmin    rdp-tcp#3          14  Active          .  8/14/2023 9:47 AM
'@

($sessionInfo | ConvertFrom-SourceTable).Where{ $_.State -eq 'Disc' }.Count
3
```