# PowerShell system idle time check and restart windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking for a PowerShell script that will when run check the windows system idle time and if 90 minutes or more will restart the computer.

Comment: I think this solution will help you a great deal, [Get idle time of machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845508/get-idle-time-of-machine)

Answer (score 0):

If the powershell of Windows is used, you can obtain `Win32_OperatingSystem`

For example

```
$ops = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$ops.FreePhysicalMemory
```

If it is powersshell 7+, you need to change the invocation method

```
$ops = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
$ops.FreePhysicalMemory
```

[collecting-information-about-computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/collecting-information-about-computers?view=powershell-7.3)

[changing-computer-state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/changing-computer-state?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: I'm certain this isn't what the OP was asking for. `Get-CimInstance` was introduced in powershell 3 too, so it is supported in windows.