# Get idle time (Win32 API) issue

Tags: powershell, winapi

I wrote a script based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846912) using the Win32 API. And https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy - in terms of interaction with Hyper-V.

```
#MouseUnlocker

Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

    public static class UserInput {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
            public uint cbSize;
            public int dwTime;
        }
    
        public static DateTime LastInput {
            get {
                DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
                DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
                return lastInput;
            }
        }

        public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
            get {
                return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
            }
        }
    
        public static double IdleSeconds {
            get {
                return IdleTime.TotalSeconds;
            }
        }

        public static int LastInputTicks {
            get {
                LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                return lii.dwTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@
    
$VMName = "Your-VMName"
$VMCS = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -Filter "ElementName='$($VMName)'"
$wheelDeltaConst = 120

$mouseWMIPath = $VMCS.GetRelated("Msvm_SyntheticMouse").__PATH 
function mouseUnlockerMove { 
param ( [int]$x, [int]$y, [int]$button ) 
    $localMouse = [wmi]$mouseWMIPath 
    $button1State1 = $localMouse.GetButtonState(1).IsDown 
    $button2State1 = $localMouse.GetButtonState(2).IsDown 
    $mouseX1 = $localMouse.HorizontalPosition 
    $mouseY1 = $localMouse.VerticalPosition 
    sleep -Milliseconds 80 
    $localMouse = [wmi]$mouseWMIPath 
    $button1State2 = $localMouse.GetButtonState(1).IsDown 
    $button2State2 = $localMouse.GetButtonState(2).IsDown 
    $mouseX2 = $localMouse.HorizontalPosition 
    $mouseY2 = $localMouse.VerticalPosition 
    if (!($button1State1 -or $button2State1 -or $button1State2 -or $button2State2)) { 
        # None of the buttons are down 
        if (($mouseX1 -eq $mouseX2) -and ($mouseY1 -eq $mouseY2)) { 
            # The mouse has not moved 
            $localMouse.SetAbsolutePosition($x,$y) | %{if ($_.ReturnValue -ne 0) {write-host "FAIL MOVE"}} 
            if ($button -ne 0) { 
                $localMouse.SetScrollPosition($button) | %{if ($_.ReturnValue -ne 0) {write-host "FAIL SCROLL"}} 
            } 
        } else {
            write-host "Warning: The mouse is moving" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        } 
    } else {
        write-host "Warning: A mouse button is down" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } 
}
while ($true) {
    if (([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleSeconds) -gt 30) { 
        $newX = random(693..782)
        $newY = random(472..512)
        $wheelDelta = $wheelDeltaConst * (random(-1..1))
        mouseUnlockerMove $newX $newY $wheelDelta
        write-host "Idle time: " ([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleSeconds) "X:" $newX "Y:" $newY "WD:" $wheelDelta
        start-sleep -Seconds (random(60))
    } else { 
        write-host "Idle time: " ([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleSeconds) "User activity"
        start-sleep -Seconds 10
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine for a month, but today I got an unexpected behavior of the seconds counter that looks mystical.

Part of output:

```
Idle time:  220,843 X: 763 Y: 512 WD: 0
Idle time:  233,093 X: 726 Y: 505 WD: 0
Idle time:  8,531 User activity
Idle time:  18,531 User activity
Idle time:  28,547 User activity
Idle time:  35,11 X: 730 Y: 509 WD: -120
Idle time:  49,391 X: 711 Y: 501 WD: 0
Idle time:  97,641 X: 726 Y: 500 WD: 0
Idle time:  127,922 X: 744 Y: 475 WD: 120
Idle time:  172,188 X: 726 Y: 504 WD: -120
Idle time:  185,438 X: 713 Y: 483 WD: 0
Idle time:  188,719 X: 707 Y: 504 WD: 120
... further, the counter value grew correctly for a few hours until a strange transition to a negative value occurred ...
Idle time:  9992,454 X: 751 Y: 478 WD: -120
Idle time:  10044,719 X: 733 Y: 476 WD: -120
Idle time:  10057,016 X: 700 Y: 500 WD: -120
Idle time:  10102,297 X: 738 Y: 490 WD: 0
Idle time:  10105,579 X: 753 Y: 497 WD: -120
Idle time:  10135,844 X: 727 Y: 474 WD: 0
Idle time:  10171,094 X: 770 Y: 507 WD: 0
Idle time:  10189,36 X: 695 Y: 501 WD: -120
Idle time:  -4284727,905 User activity
Idle time:  -4284717,889 User activity
Idle time:  -4284707,874 User activity
Idle time:  -4284697,874 User activity
Idle time:  -4284687,874 User activity
Idle time:  -4284677,858 User activity
Idle time:  -4284667,858 User activity
Idle time:  -4284657,842 User activity
Idle time:  -4284647,842 User activity
Idle time:  -4284637,827 User activity
Idle time:  -4284627,827 User activity
Idle time:  -4284617,811 User activity
Idle time:  -4284607,796 User activity
Idle time:  -4284597,796 User activity
Idle time:  -4284587,78 User activity
... i break script ...
```

Why did the time become negative?

I checked all the data types of variables, experimentally tried to cause them to overflow. Nothing. Did I miss something?

**UPDATE:**

I also remembered that the time synchronization (which in theory could have affected) was a day ago, at that time the script was not running yet.

Comment: This might not actually be the problem, but you should check the return value from ```GetLastInputInfo``` - a zero return indicates a failure, and using its output in that case will give unexpected results - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo - always check the docs when calling win32 api members, and make sure you handle error conditions properly to avoid strange downstream behaviour with invalid outputs.

Comment: @mclayton, Thank you for such a quick response! It is not difficult to add processing of such an error condition, but I want to understand the causes of the problem. Following the advice, I will add some debug information to the output, and will try to cause an error again

Comment: Btw, ticks *aren't* milliseconds - if you look at ```TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond``` it tells you there's 10,000 ticks per millisecond. If you're adding *ticks* to a ```DateTime``` as if they were *milliseconds* you're actually adding 10,000 times the amount of ticks than you have, and your "month" of running would actually be 833 years in "ticks are milliseconds"-time, so you could *possibly* be encountering a leap year or some other weird distant-future calendar artifact.

Comment: "Why did the time become negative?"
According to the Doc:[GetLastInputInfo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) The tick count when the last input event was received is not guaranteed to be incremental. In some cases, the value might be less than the tick count of a prior event. For example, this can be caused by a timing gap between the raw input thread and the desktop thread.